# How to install Ubuntu 13.04 if I don't know how to rezise my partitions?

Tags: installation, partitioning, 13.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 (or whatever the latest version is but I'm pretty sure that's it). When I get to the sliders for partition size it goes to the advanced partition-viewer and there's a lot of different things starting with /dev/ when I try to just continue without touching anything it says

"Some of the partitions you created are to small. Please make the following partitions at least this large:

```
      /2.9 GB
```

If you do not go back to the partitioner and increase the size of these partitions the installation may fail."

How do I fix this? Is there an auto-partitioner where the installer takes care of it automatically? Do I/ how do I fix it myself?

Comment: The installer DOES handle partitioning automatically. Just do not choose "Something else". But you need to have enough space on the disk.

Answer (score 2):

if you need to do advanced partitioning I suggest using gparted to handle that then just use the something else option in the installer and just tell it what to use each partition for

less than 2.9GB is too small to install ubuntu in it entirety to, it is fine for a part of it,
this video covers advanced partitioning:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sPGEwqoXA0

If you are trying to dualboot with windows you need to resize windows to make room (defrag windows 1st, unless you are using a ssd)